# 2010 workflow to send email on one field change keeps sending on any field change

Tags: 2010, workflow, email, designer

I have a 2010 SharePoint workflow that is set to start when an item is changed.  Within the workflow, I have logic that is testing to see if a specific field changed and if so, send an email.  I am doing this by storing the "before" value in a hidden field, comparing it to the new value and if they aren't equal, send the email.  The problem is that the email is being sent even when this field isn't changing.  I can't figure out why.  I've moved some logic around in the workflow, thinking that might be the cause, but it hasn't fixed the problem. I've confirmed that both the hidden field and the specific field values are the same.  Then I edit the item using a form, keeping the specific field the same but editing another field and the email is still being sent.  Below is a snapshot.

[image: screenshot]

Update:  Both of the comparison fields are person/group fields (comparing on Display Name).  I've confirmed their values match prior to editing the form for the list item.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.SE! I don't know why it isn't working, however, you can simplify your workflow a bit by putting all of your entries into one if/then statement. There's no reason to complicate the workflow. You don't tell us what the value equates to, as in, is it a date/time stamp? What kind of value are you comparing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably committing a fatal faux pas here, but I think I solved my own problem.  Paulster, your question led me to the issue.

I mentioned twice that I've confirmed that the two comparison fields had the same value.  I did this by adding both to a list view.  They both displayed the same person, in Display Name format.  But, for whatever reason, if I tried comparing on Display Name format, the workflow always saw the values as not matching.  Once I changed the format to String, the workflow started working correctly.

I hope this helps someone else who may have the same problem.